# ckEditor in modal Does not works when reopened without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, laravel-5, ckeditor4.x

I'm having isssue in CKEditor load in my modal (of Material Design Template).
It works on first load of modal.
But when I open modal by ajax call without re-loading(refreshing) page then CKeditor does not works to give text to textarea. 
 It gives error while CKEditor load in console stating 
"  *TypeError: $(...).get(...) is undefined* " in Firefox 
" *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefined* " in Chrome 
My jquery method is following which i call on each modal open.

```
    //being callled in ajax success and modal open
var description = CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );
loadEditorData();


// Function to get and Load Editor's contents.
function loadEditorData() {
 setTimeout(function(){
         $( $("#cke_1_contents iframe" ).get(0).contentWindow.document ).keypress( function() {
             setTimeout(function(){
              var editorText = CKEDITOR.instances.description.getData();
              console.log(editorText);
              $("#description").html(editorText);
              }, 10);
            });
     }, 5000);
 }
```